# What does "-c" option do for Swift compiler (swiftc)?

Tags: swift, swift-compiler

I noticed there is "-c" option in `swiftc`, what does this option do?

> swiftc ... -c ....

Is there an official document about this? I couldn't find it from `man`, `--help` or online :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-c` is `-emit-object`:

```
$ swiftc --help
OVERVIEW: Swift compiler

USAGE: swiftc [options] 

MODES:
  -dump-ast              Parse and type-check input file(s) and dump AST(s)
  -dump-parse            Parse input file(s) and dump AST(s)
  -dump-scope-maps 
                         Parse and type-check input file(s) and dump the scope map(s)
  -dump-type-info        Output YAML dump of fixed-size types from all imported modules
  -dump-type-refinement-contexts
                         Type-check input file(s) and dump type refinement contexts(s)
  -emit-assembly         Emit assembly file(s) (-S)
  -emit-bc               Emit LLVM BC file(s)
  -emit-executable       Emit a linked executable
  -emit-imported-modules Emit a list of the imported modules
  -emit-ir               Emit LLVM IR file(s)
  -emit-library          Emit a linked library
  -emit-object           Emit object file(s) (-c)
  -emit-sibgen           Emit serialized AST + raw SIL file(s)
  -emit-sib              Emit serialized AST + canonical SIL file(s)
  -emit-silgen           Emit raw SIL file(s)
  -emit-sil              Emit canonical SIL file(s)
  -index-file            Produce index data for a source file
  -parse                 Parse input file(s)
  -print-ast             Parse and type-check input file(s) and pretty print AST(s)
  -resolve-imports       Parse and resolve imports in input file(s)
  -typecheck             Parse and type-check input file(s)
```

Comment: Thanks! It's hidden in the description.